# refactoring mandatory map.get java code

Tags: java

Please, any ideas on how to refactor this java code so I don't have to repeat those code blocks 3 (or more) times?

```
Integer id = null;
try {
    id = (Integer)extradata.get("id");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error(e);
}

if (id == null) {
    logger.error("no id set");
    task.setStatus(Status.ERROR);
    DBService.updateTaskStatus(conn, false, task);
    conn.commit();
    return;
}

String name = null;
try {
    name = (String)extradata.get("name");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error(e);
}

if (name == null) {
    logger.error("no name set");
    task.setStatus(Status.ERROR);
    DBService.updateTaskStatus(conn, false, task);
    conn.commit();
    return;
}

String city = null;
try {
    city = (String)extradata.get("city");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error(e);
}

if (city == null) {
    logger.error("no city set");
    task.setStatus(Status.ERROR);
    DBService.updateTaskStatus(conn, false, task);
    conn.commit();
    return;
}
```

Comment: What do they have in common?  Where do they differ?  Make a function that uses the former & takes the latter as parameters.

Comment: And do you *really* want to keep going in the face of all exceptions? Catching `Exception` is almost *always* a bad idea.

Comment: yes, that's the basic idea, as I have done in many other cases... but it seems harder in this case because it seems weird for an external function that would just get the value of a variable to commit the mysql connection (not only to receive the conn as parameter)

Comment: @JonSkeet, it doesn't keep going... the "if" right after the catch will return (I could put this behavior in the catch itself, but then it wouldn't happen in case the value was null because it didn't exist instead of an exception)

Comment: @Lem0n: It keeps going in that it treats an absent value in the same way as something ghastly going wrong. In particular, it terminates normally (with a `return` statement) rather than propagating an exception. What exceptions are you actually concerned about, that *don't* indicate something so wrong that you would want to terminate anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer id = null;
String name = null;
String city = null;

try {
    id = (Integer)extradata.get("id");
    name = (String)extradata.get("name");
    city = (String)extradata.get("city");
catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error(e);
}

if (id == null || name == null || city == null) {
    String msg = (id == null ? "id" : name == null ? "name" : "city");
    logger.error("no "+msg+" set");
    task.setStatus(Status.ERROR);
    DBService.updateTaskStatus(conn, false, task);
    conn.commit();
    return;
}
```

Comment: @Cruncher come on, this is not so bad :D

Comment: @alfasin it's not immediately obvious the order of priority

Comment: @Cruncher in Java (unlike PHP for example) it's very obvious - the order goes from left to right

Answer (score 3):

You can use a static generic method:

```
private static final <T> T getValue(Map<String, Object> extradata, String key, Class<T> clazz) {
    Object val = extradata.get(key);
    if (val == null) {
        handleNullVariable("name");
        return null;
    }        
    return clazz.cast(val);
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
Integer id = getValue(extradata, "id", Integer.class);
String name = getValue(extradata, "name", String.class);
```

Comment: +1 beautiful! (avoiding exceptions is always a good idea!) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method that checks a string for `null`, and updates the status, like this:

```
private static boolean isValid(
    Object obj
,   String msg
,   Connection conn
,   Task task) {
    if (obj != null) return true;
    logger.error(msg);
    task.setStatus(Status.ERROR);
    DBService.updateTaskStatus(conn, false, task);
    conn.commit();
    return false;
}
```

Now you can change the main method to call `checkValidString` repeatedly:

```
Integer id = null;
try {
    id = (Integer)extradata.get("id");
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error(e);
}
if (!isValid(id, "no id set", conn, task)) return;

String name = null;
try {
    name = (String)extradata.get("name");
} catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error(e);
}
if (!isValid(name, "no name set", conn, task)) return;

String city = null;
try {
    city = (String)extradata.get("city");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    logger.error(e);
}
if (!isValid(city, "no city set", conn, task)) return;
```

Comment: Nice, but he still needs to use 3 different try/catch with this solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Integer id = null;
    try {
        id = (Integer)extradata.get("id");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }

    if (id == null) {
        handleNullVariable("id");
        return;
    }

    String name = null;
    try {
        name = (String)extradata.get("name");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }

    if (name == null) {
        handleNullVariable("name");
        return;
    }

    String city = null;
    try {
        city = (String)extradata.get("city");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }

    if (city == null) {
        handleNullVariable("city");
        return;
    }

    void handleNullVariable(String variableName)
    {
    logger.error("no "+ variableName + " set");
     task.setStatus(Status.ERROR);
        DBService.updateTaskStatus(conn, false, task);
        conn.commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class NotFoundException extends Exception {
}
...
Object getValue(String name) {
    Object res;
    try {
        res=extradata.get(name);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
    if (res == null) {
        logger.error("no "+name+" set");
        task.setStatus(Status.ERROR);
        DBService.updateTaskStatus(conn, false, task);
        conn.commit();
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
}
...
try {
    Integer id = (Integer)getValue("id");
    String name  = (String )getValue("name");
    String city  = (String )getValue("city");
 } catch(Exception e) {
    return;
 }
```

Comment: the problem I see with that solution is that the getValue() function would need parameters extradata, conn and task (unless I wanna declare them as fields and also take care of thread-safety), which seems ugly (ie, out of scope of what it should do)

Comment: and now, are `extradata, conn and task` local variables?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <E> E getData(String key)
{
    E ret = null;
    try {
        ret = (E)extradata.get(key);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }

    if (ret == null) {
        throw new Exception(key);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Call it with

```
try
{
    Integer id = getData("id");
    String name = getData("name");
    String city = getData("city");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    logger.error("no " + e.getMessagE() + " set");
    task.setStatus(Status.ERROR);
    DBService.updateTaskStatus(conn, false, task);
    conn.commit();
    return;
}
```

Comment: same comment as for Alexei: the problem I see with that solution is that the getData() function would need parameters extradata, conn and task (unless I wanna declare them as fields and also take care of thread-safety), which seems ugly (ie, out of scope of what it should do)

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem with passing parameters is

Comment: I think usually people will assume a function called "getData" won't commit something to the database. Of course you could call it getDataAndActOnErrors, but for me it seems a hint something is not nice

Comment: @Lem0n I edited it so the error handling happens outside. also, this requires you to pass less into the method